# Switching between two monitors on HDMI / DVI, different resolutions

Tags: hdmi

In the living room, I've a PC connected to the 1080p plasma TV, over HDMI (with a DVI/HDMI adapter plugged into the GeForce card).

In the bedroom, I've another PC, connected to a 1920x1200 LCD screen, pretty high quality, calibrated with a dedicated calibration device, and so on. I use it to process the RAW files from my mirrorless camera.

I want to get rid of the PC in the bedroom, upgrade the PC in the living room to Windows 7, and move the LCD next to it. Then I'll have to switch the output between the TV and the LCD.

What kind of device for switching the output between the two displays would I need?

There's a concern here, that the resolutions are different - 1920x1080 on the TV, 1920x1200 on the LCD. What will happen when I switch back and forth? I want to run both monitors at their respective native resolutions.

Comment: Your graphic card should have two outputs. You can use Window’s builtin display settings.